# Should I edit sources.list*?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, software-sources

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 14.04, which is also when I started using the nvidia 331 proprietary driver. When installing updates, I would get prompted with the 'Not all updates can be installed' message. Because I didn't know whether it shows up because of the distribution upgrade or the nvidia driver, I search around for a bit.

I found a potential solution using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

However, I also learned about **/etc/apt/sources.list**. I had a look inside mines and 
found mostly saucy and raring sources inside **sources.list.distUpgrade**, and one non-trusty source inside the main main **sources.list**:

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of **sources.list.save** and **sources.list.distUpgrade**? Should I remove/modify them?
2. Should I remove the raring source in **sources.list**?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sources.list.save` and `sources.list.distUpgrade` were created by the Upgrade Manager and refer to the entries before the upgrade. Files not ending in `.list` aren't read in and are there for backup purposes, so you can safely delete `*.list.save` and `*.list.distUpgrade`.

Regarding the `raring` entries, I would change them to `trusty`, although this should have automatically happened when you upgraded from Raring to Saucy.